# mysql : how to change schema between 2 tables

Tags: mysql

Hello so i have the following schema :

hotels:

```
hotel_code int(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
hotel_name char(20) default NULL,
city char(20) default NULL,
address char(20) default NULL,
hotel_rank int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
phone char(10) default NULL,
number_of_rooms int(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY  (hotel_code));
```

rooms:

```
hotel_code int(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
room_number int(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
type char(20) default NULL,
beds int(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
price int(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY  (hotel_code, room_number));
```

now i'm trying to achieve the following :

my query : 
show the list of rooms that their price are between 170-380
 in the following scheme :

```
hotel_code, hotel_name, city, room_number, price
```

and make sure it is ranked by `hotel_rank` and

```
price
```

i know how to do the 2 things in separate but not to combine them i tried everything ...any tips?

```
a = SELECT hotel_code, room_number, price FROM rooms WHERE price BETWEEN 170 AND 380 ORDER BY price;
b = SELECT hotel_code, hotel_name, city FROM hotels ORDER BY hotel_rank;
```

Comment: Code formatting is best done with the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

This a really basic SQL query, and it has nothing to do with "changing schema between 2 tables".

Using `LEFT JOIN` (there are other alternatives) you can combine tables using a column with a value that both tables share and then show the results you need.

```
SELECT H.hotel_code, H.hotel_name, H.city, R.room_number, R.price
FROM hotels H LEFT JOIN rooms R ON H.hotel_code = R.hotel_code
WHERE R.price BETWEEN 170 AND 380 
ORDER BY H.hotel_rank,R.price;
```

I recommend you to read some basic tutorials (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)